# Copying text to two inputs with the same ID

Tags: javascript, html

When I wrote something in the first input, second input showed it, but:

a) What if i want see text from input "2" showed in input "3"?

HTML:

```
<input id="1" type="text" oninput=al() /></br>
<input id="2" disabled="disabled" ></br>
<input id="3" disabled="disabled">
```

JS:

```
function al() {
    var a = document.getElementById("1").value;
    var result = a;
    var ab = document.getElementById("2");
    ab.value=a;
}
```

b) What if I want to see text from input "1" in two inputs named "2"?
HTML:

```
<input id="1" type="text" oninput=al() /></br>
<input id="2" disabled="disabled" ></br>
<input id="2" disabled="disabled">
```

JS:

```
function al() {
    var a = document.getElementById("1").value;
    var result = a;
    var ab = document.getElementById("2");
    ab.value=a;
}
```

Comment: Why would you name 2 inputs with the same ID?

Comment: Duplicate ID is invalid in HTML.  So no. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id and https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2

Comment: Any answer for this outside that IT IS INVALID, propagates the false assumption that duplicate ID's are OK when they are not, it is invalid HTML and always has been to have duplicate id's.  I consider that browsers "allow/handle" this to be a bug as that is not the specification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Answer A:** To show the same value in an input with ID `2` and an input with ID `3`:

```
function al() {
    var a1 = document.getElementById("1").value;
    var a2 = document.getElementById("2");
    var a3 = document.getElementById("3");
    a2.value = a3.value = a1;
}
```

**Answer B:** Using elements with the same ID is wrong and will result in an invalid HTML document. To achieve your goal, you can set both elements with a certain class (`classA` at the example below), then you can use `document.querySelectorAll` which returns an array of elements, and then set their value with an index `[0]` and `[1]`:

```
<input id="1" type="text" oninput=al() /></br>
<input class='classA' disabled="disabled" ></br>
<input class='classA' disabled="disabled">

function al() {
    var a = document.getElementById("1").value;
    var result = a;
    var ab = document.querySelectorAll("[class='classA']");
    ab[0].value = ab[1].value = a;
}
```

Comment: The first part of this is OK, the second, not so much.  I suggest you alter to use the class attribute perhaps?

Comment: See me comments on the question.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I have one more question. What if I want something like this?
https://jsbin.com/hepehelipe/edit?html,js,output
Do you understand what I mean?

Comment: @tymeq like what?

Comment: @tymeq If the answer above helped, accepting it as correct would be appreciated. Now about that link, what is your question?

Comment: So, I'm looking for the same result as above, but I want to gain this in the different way (with use of this two functions). As you see, this code doesn't work, so something is wrong (second function doesn't work). Do you know why?

Comment: If you dont' understand. I writing something into input "1" and this is displayed in the input "2". This is function "al()". Now, second function, "aal()" takes value from input "2" and displayed it in the input "3".

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can't have two element with the same ID.
Second to copy from one to another, it's better use the `keyDown`, `keyUp` or `onchange` events.
E.g.

```
  <input type="text" id="1" onchange="copypaste()"/>
  <input type="text" id="2"/>
```

```js
  function copypaste() {
    var  first = document.getElementById("1")
    var  second = document.getElementById("2")
    second.value = first.value
  }
```